# Calculation of the salience function (Klapuri 2006)

Tags: pitch

I am reading [this](http://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/37729687/klap2006ismir.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1496701048&Signature=R1eDkqm7cy%2FM653fbE7zpil904M%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DMultiple_Fundamental_Frequency_Estimatio.pdf) paper here and I wanted to check my understanding regarding the salience function:
$$
\hat{s}(\tau)=\sum_{m=1}^M g(\tau, m) \max_{k\in \kappa_{\tau, m}}\lvert Y(k)\rvert
$$

Where the set $\kappa_{\tau, m}$ defines a range of frequency bins in the vicinity of the $m^{\rm th}$ overtone partial of the F0 candidate.

We want to find the maximum of $Y(k)$ for those k. But k is a frequency. And Y is, according to Klapuri the discrete STFT of the signal. I don't understand what the STFT on a given frequency is.

- The STFT represents a 2D vector so $Y(k)$ must be a vector, right?
- How do we find the max of list of vectors?
- Is something in my understanding wrong?

So let's say we are testing the salience of the period 0.002. We start with $m=1$, and get $g(\tau, m)$. Then what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that STFT is a function of 2 variables (usually x-axis is time and y-axis is frequency). The author is a bit careless in calling $Y(k)$ the STFT. What he really means is that $Y(k)$ is a fixed column (i.e. fixed time slice) of the STFT. The salience function is more carefully defined by the same author in this paper titled [Multipitch analysis of polyphonic music and speech
signals using an auditory mode](https://www.cs.tut.fi/sgn/arg/klap/ameff.pdf) Eq. 13, where he uses a subscript $t$ to denote a fixed time slice of the STFT.

Comment: Yes, that indeed makes much more sense!!! Thanks.

Comment: Therefore, it is in reality $Y_{t}(k)$, which returns an amplitude, right?

Comment: Yes. $Y_t(k)$ is the spectrum from a "time slice" at time $t$, which is a 1-D function of frequency and you can look for the maximum magnitude in this vector.